# How to update sql all rows in CI

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table below:

```
ID________User____________Pass________Email
1_________Admin.website___abc_________ad@web.com
2_________mod.website_____123_________mod@web.com
3_________user.website____abc_________user@gmail.com

...................................................

n_________user_n.website__pass_______mail@gmail.com
```

How can i use active record to update all user rows with replacing

```
.website
```

with

```
.web
```

the fastest?

Answer (score 1):

Use direct sql instead of codeigniter active record for this purpose. See [Replace()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '.website', '.web')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%website%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine CI

```
$this->db->set('User', "REPLACE (User, '.website', '.web')", FALSE); 
$this->db->update("tablename");
```